# How can I specify order of fields in Attrs?

Tags: python, python-attrs

Taking from `attrs` example [here](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html#converting-to-collections-types) but adding `group_id` & `name`. I want to create data classes so I can then export them to JSON using `json.dump()`.

```
@define
class User:
    email: str
    password: str
    name: str = field(default="No name")

@define
class UserList:
    users: list[User]
    group_id: str = field(default=str(uuid4()), on_setattr=frozen)

json.dump(asdict(UserList([User("jane@doe.invalid", "s33kred"),
                 User("joe@doe.invalid", "p4ssw0rd")]),
       filter=lambda attr, value: attr.name != "password"))
```

That prints out this:

```
{"users": [{"email": "jane@doe.invalid"}, {"email": "joe@doe.invalid"}, {"name": "No name"}], "group-id": "a9fc0c10-125f-4c65-a901-ac16e3b57bc7"}
```

However, my issue is that I want `group-id` to be at the very top and `name` to be the first one in the list. Something like this:

```
{"group-id": "a9fc0c10-125f-4c65-a901-ac16e3b57bc7", "users": [{"name": "No name"}, {"email": "jane@doe.invalid"}, {"email": "joe@doe.invalid"}]}
```

It seems that `attrs` organise them on initialisation and because `group-id` & `name` have a default value, I am unable to place it at the top.

Is there a way to instruct the order?

Answer (score 0):

Which Python version? As of Python 3.7+ [dictionaries are insertion ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) so `asdict` should respect the order of the fields as you provided them.

You could also change the `dict_factory` arg of [`attr.asdict`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.asdict) to use `collections.OrderedDict` to enforce this otherwise.

Comment: I've updated the issue. My problem is that fields with default values have to go below fields without default values. So they don't look in order even in the class. I wondered if `attrs` would have a way to instruct the order/format

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to sort your keys in the end? You can do it by passing `sort_keys=True`. For example:

```
import json
print(
    json.dumps(
        {"users": [
            {"email": "jane@doe.invalid"},
            {"email": "joe@doe.invalid"}
        ],
            "group-id": "a9fc0c10-125f-4c65-a901-ac16e3b57bc7"},
        sort_keys=True
    )
)
```

**Output:**

```
{"group-id": "a9fc0c10-125f-4c65-a901-ac16e3b57bc7", "users": [{"email": "jane@doe.invalid"}, {"email": "joe@doe.invalid"}]}
```